# Python - lookahead driver for a parsing chain

Tags: python, parsing

This is retroactive followup (that is, logically this is a followup, chronologically it isn't) to this question: [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186734/python-basis-of-a-parser-library).

I'm writing a parser combinator library in Python. An important thing that must be in the library is ability for a parser chain to perform some lookahead, so analogs of regex `(.*)foo` are 1) useful, 2) work as expected, and not fail because `(.*)` has gobbled up all input.

I've concocted a solution for this, which seems to work based on my testing, but I want to see if it can be improved in any way. My main concerns are

1. Correctness - are weird edge-cases accomodated by my algorithm?
2. Performance - could it be faster?

There's also a couple of minor points I would like to know:

1. Is simply attaching an extra field to a function like `greedy` and `reluctant` do acceptable, or should I wrap changed functions in a class instead?
2. I'm doing `except ParsingEnd as end: raise end` in a couple of places as a visual cue that I remember about those. Should I drop it?

The algorithm is as follows:

1. Traverse the chain of parsers, feeding output of one to another
2. If a parser that should perform lookahead is encountered, start adding all parsers to a 'retry chain', whether they perform lookahead or not.
3. If some parser fails, fall back to the last parser with lookahead and change the portion of input it's allowed to operate on.
4. Reset input restrictions for all parsers to the right of this parser, and retry parsing from this point.
5. If all combinations of input restrictions were tried unsuccessfully, fail.

Now for the code. The entire project can be seen in this repo: [link](https://github.com/mpevnev/epp), in a frozen branch `review-03022018` (core file). I'll post critical points below.

Here's the `chain` function, where lookahead driver is located. It expects an iterable of parsers as the first argument, where a parser is just a callable that takes one State object and returns a new one. If a parser fails, it's expected to raise a `ParsingFailure` exception. A parser is marked as having lookahead capabilities with `greedy` and `reluctant` functions.

```
def chain(funcs, combine=True, stop_on_failure=False):
    """
    Create a parser that chains a given iterable of parsers together, using
    output of one parser as input for another.

    If 'combine' is truthy, combine 'parsed's of the parsers in the chain,
    otherwise use the last one.

    If 'stop_on_failure' is truthy, stop parsing instead of failing it when a
    parser in the chain raises a ParsingFailure exception. Note that this also
    includes parsers with lookahead, effectively disabling it.

    A note on using iterators in chains: if supplied 'funcs' is an iterator,
    there is a possibility of 'funcs' being exausted on the first attempt to
    parse, with subsequent attempts silently succeeding because that's the
    default behaviour for empty 'funcs'. If you want to run your chain several
    times - be it because of lookahead or for different reasons - make sure to
    wrap the iterator in list or some other *reusable* iterable (or call
    'reuse_iter' on it, if it comes from a function).
    """
    def res(state):
        """ A chain of parsers. """
        pieces = _CachedAppender() if combine else None
        def maybe_combine(state):
            """ Concatenate 'parsed's if 'combine' is truthy. """
            if combine:
                state.parsed = "".join(pieces)
            return state
        lookahead_chain = None
        for parser in funcs:
            if lookahead_chain is None and has_lookahead(parser):
                lookahead_chain = _CachedAppender()
            if lookahead_chain is not None or has_lookahead(parser):
                parser = _restrict(parser)
                lookahead_chain.append(parser)
            try:
                state = parser(state)
                if combine:
                    pieces.append(state.parsed)
            except ParsingEnd as end:
                raise end
            except ParsingFailure as failure:
                if stop_on_failure:
                    return maybe_combine(state)
                if lookahead_chain is None:
                    raise failure
                pos = len(lookahead_chain) - 1
                while True:
                    try_shift = _shift(lookahead_chain, pos)
                    if try_shift is None:
                        raise ParsingFailure(
                            "Failed to find a combination of inputs that allows  "
                            "successful parsing")
                    _reset_chain(lookahead_chain, try_shift)
                    state, failed = _try_chain(lookahead_chain, try_shift, pieces)
                    if state is None:
                        pos = failed
                        continue
                    break
        return maybe_combine(state)
    return res
```

There are a couple helper things that `chain` uses (directly or not). The most important is `_RestrictedParser`, which is a wrapper over a parser that remembers two things: the state it took as an argument the last time and which portion of input it is allowed to operate on:

```
class _RestrictedParser():
    """ A parser that only operates on a restricted portion of input. """

    def __init__(self, parser):
        self.parser = parser
        self.lookahead = get_lookahead(parser)
        self.delta = 0
        self.state_before = None

    def __call__(self, state):
        self.state_before = state
        if self.lookahead is None:
            return self.parser(state)
        if self.lookahead is Lookahead.GREEDY:
            return _subparse(state, self.parser, len(state.left) - self.delta)
        # is reluctant
        return _subparse(state, self.parser, self.delta)

    def overrestricted(self):
        """
        Return True if restrictions have reached their maximum - that is, if
        either allowed input portion is shrinked into an empty string, or has
        extended beyond the bounds of leftover input.
        """
        return self.delta > len(self.state_before.left)

    def reset(self):
        """ Reset restrictions. """
        self.delta = 0
        self.state_before = None

    def restrict_more(self):
        """ Increase restriction level on the input. """
        self.delta += 1
```

`_subparse` simply splits a State object in two at the specified position and uses a given parser on the first part, then joins leftovers with the second part.

The second important thing is `_shift`, which attempts to restrict parsers starting at a given position and going to the left. If a parser cannot be restricted further, the next parser is also restricted (and if it also cannot, the next is tried, and so on). If all restriction configurations were tried the function will return `None`, otherwise it'll return the index of the last restricted parser.

`_reset_chain` helper function used by `chain` simply resets restrictions on parsers starting at a given position and to the right.

Finally, `_try_chain` attempts to parse the state of its first `_RestrictedParser` using current configuration of restrictions in the chain:

```
def _try_chain(parsers, from_pos, pieces):
    """
    Try to parse the state the first parser in the chain remembers.

    Return a tuple (state, index of the first parser to fail).
    In case of failure, 'state' will be None.

    Also, if 'pieces' is not None, append every parsed chunk to it, having
    first dropped every invalidated piece. If an attempt to parse fails,
    'pieces' will not be affected.
    """
    state = parsers[from_pos].state_before
    i = from_pos
    new_pieces = None if pieces is None else deque()
    for i in range(from_pos, len(parsers)):
        try:
            state = parsers[i](state)
            if pieces is not None:
                new_pieces.append(state.parsed)
        except ParsingFailure:
            return (None, i)
        except ParsingEnd as end:
            raise end
    if pieces is not None:
        # '-1' is here because the last parser does not contribute a piece, as
        # it has failed
        pieces.drop(len(parsers) - from_pos - 1)
        pieces.extend(new_pieces)
    return state, i
```

The rest of used helpers are:

1. `_CachedAppender` - just a simple wrapper over a deque that sort of allows faster indexing if the deque changes not very often.
2. `_restrict` - wraps a parser with lookahead in `_RestrictedParser` and does nothing to a parser without lookahead.

Mentioned `greedy` and `reluctant` are simply:

```
def greedy(parser):
    """ Return a greedy version of 'parser'. """
    try:
        if parser.lookahead is Lookahead.GREEDY:
            return parser
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    res = lambda state: parser(state)
    res.lookahead = Lookahead.GREEDY
    return res
```

I do not want to pollute the post with extraneous code so I don't post the code of everything I mention, so if anything needs to be added, please tell me.

Comment: This question asks us to review the most complicated part of your parsing system. This approach isn't likely to get the best results out of Code Review. First, in order to review this code, we would need a thorough understanding of the foundation of your parsing system, but no-one here is likely to have such knowledge or expertise. Second, until we've reviewed the foundation, we can't be sure that the superstructure is on a firm footing. (cont...)

Comment: For better results, start by asking us to review the foundation of the parser: the `State` class, the `parse` function, and so on. (There's much that could be improved in these parts of the system.) Once we've reviewed the foundations (and you've fixed the review points) then it would make sense to present the more complicated code for review. (cont...)

Comment: I hope this advice is not too discouraging — it looks like an interesting system, but in order to do a decent review, we have to start with the foundations, not the penthouse.

Comment: @GarethReess This makes a lot of sense, and advice seems quite solid. I'll write up a question about the foundations shortly. What would be the best thing to do with this question? Leave it as it is until the new question is answered (and code is fixed), or delete it and then write a new one?

Comment: It's up to you, but there's nothing wrong with leaving this question open for now — it is a reasonable question, and maybe I'm too pessimistic and some expert in parser combinators will show up.